After Start Compute VM Instance in GCP my VM external IP and SSH doesn't accessible
In Google Cloud Platform ( gcp ) I have some Compute VM where host my website. I need to stop some VM temporary. After passed some hour, I need to start VM again. My Compute VM has been started but My VM external IP address & SSH are not accessable. I also added screenshot of SSH error. When I try to access ip address from terminal/browser then doesn't reached.
How can I fix this issue.
SSH Eror below text
Code: 4003
Reason: failed to connect to backend

Connection to VM is refused.

SSH Error screenshot

I try to access SSH & check Firewall rules.

The following errors might occur when you connect to your VM from the Google Cloud console or the gcloud CLI:
The Google Cloud console:
-- Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed

-- Code: 4003

-- Reason: failed to connect to backend

The gcloud CLI:
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Error while connecting [4003: 'failed to connect to backend'].

These errors occur when you try to use SSH to connect to a VM that doesn't have a public IP address and for which you haven't configured Identity-Aware Proxy on port 22.
To resolve this issue Create a firewall rule on port 22 that allows ingress traffic from Identity-Aware Proxy.
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-ssh-ingress-from-iap \
  --direction=INGRESS \
  --action=allow \
  --rules=tcp:22 \
  --source-ranges=35.235.240.0/20

It allows ingress traffic from the IP range 35.235.240.0/20. This range contains all IP addresses that IAP uses for TCP forwarding.
To learn more about it, see the next documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#failed_to_connect_to_backend
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#gcloud
